# Retrieving wrong cookie (I'm using codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I never worked with cookies before so I'm probably messing up really hard.

Thing is. I set a cookie and then try to echo it for testing. If I inspect my browser, it shows me the cookie is there, but the cookie being fetched is always one cookie previous to the one last created. Here is what I'm doing:

```
function set_cookie_test($user_id)
{ 
  $this->load->helper('cookie');
  $this->load->module('site_security');
  $this->load->module('site_settings');

  $now_time = time();
  $one_day  = 86400;
  $one_week = $one_day * 7;
  $one_week_ahead = $now_time + $one_week;

  $data['cookie_code'] = $this->site_security->generate_random_string(128);      // the cookie_code on the table is 128 chars long
  $data['user_id']     = $user_id;
  $data['expiry_date'] = $one_week_ahead;

  $this->_insert($data);

  $cookie_name = $this->site_settings->_get_cookie_name();

  set_cookie($cookie_name, $value = $data['cookie_code'], $expire = $data['expiry_date'], $domain = '', $path = '/', $prefix = '', $secure = FALSE, $httponly = FALSE);

  $cookieVal = get_cookie($cookie_name);
  echo $cookieVal; die();
}
```

This is what happens after I log in (when I call this function)

[image: crazy_cookie]

As you can see, the cookie in the browser has a value of 8XvaQZjWX7... This is the current cookie, it matches my DB.

[image: db_cookie]

The previous cookie value in my db is the one being echoed out. I need to figure this out for the following reason:

Whenever I use sessions for the login, I set userdata so I can retrieve the user's info to display his name and avatar on the screen, for example.

I need to be able to do the same when I use cookies...

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: [PHP Sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) offer the same functionality without the hassle of dealing with cookies.

Comment: As for your issue, `get_cookie()` retrieves the cookie value as sent by the browser on page request. Setting a new value will not change the one that this `get_cookie()` returns.

Comment: Yes, I'm used to working with sessions and it's great, but i wanted to implement a 'remember me' feature, that's why I'm using cookies. If the user checks the 'remember me' box, I set a cookie, otherwise I set a session... Is this the wrong approach?

Comment: @jhmckimm Thanks a lot, now I realized what I was doing wrong.